# Using MFMailComposeViewController in storyboard does not work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uistoryboard, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In storyboard I can setup a segue from a button to a `UIViewController` and make it appear modally. This works fine. However when I change the class in storyboard from `UIViewController` to `MFMailComposeViewController`, it does not work at all. All that appears is a navigation bar at the top with the rest of the display being filled with black. Am I taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and I could not seem to figure out what the problem was either. You can either

1. Fall back to a `IBAction` and create the `MFMailComposeViewController` instance your self and display it.
2. If you want to keep using Storyboards, which I think is desirable then you might create a wrapper-class that internally instantiates the `MFMailComposeViewController` and then functions as a proxy object and thus propagates `viewDid***` and `viewWill***`-methods to the wrapped class and also returning the wrapped VC's view in a readonly `view` property... You get the idea.

Comment: I just implemented it in code in the end. Seemed easiest. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by Besi:

1. `&nbsp;`
2. `&nbsp;`
3. Subclass `MFMailComposeViewController` and override `initWithCoder:` method.

Example:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    return [super init];
}
```

Then it will work with storyboards, but I think your outlets / tags / other definitions from storyboard scene won't be applied (you have to configure mail composer inside your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method).

Comment: I really like the simplicity of your solution.